# How to List only the records of logged User - SuiteCRM Version 7.10.4 Sugar Version 6.5.25 (Build 344)

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to **show only the records of logged in user** and hide all other users records of all modules in Suitecrm and only Admin or any other ROLE  USERS should be able to see all records

I have tried setting up the Security Suite Group Management, But failed

And also tried 
In the following path i have
***../custom/Extension/modules/my_module/views/view.list.php*** in ***listViewProcess*** function i have used the following code

```
    global $current_user;
    $user_name = $current_user->first_name." ".$current_user->last_name;

    $this->processSearchForm();
    $this->params['custom_where'] = " AND my_module.assigned_user_name = '$current_user->name' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create Role management. Please follow the below setps:

1. Goto admin -> Click on "Role Management" -> Click on Create Role.
2. Give Any name for example "Regular User" as simply click on the save button.
3. After saving the Role you find the role management screen.
4. Here you can set the owner permission to list and view action of all module.
5. At the end you need to selet user to which you want to display records based on the role.

For more detail please refer to this link:
https://docs.suitecrm.com/admin/administration-panel/roles-and-security-groups/#_role_management

Note: You can create multiple role based on diffrent user.

Hope this helps!

Thanks.